# Does form.submit in JavaScript hit HTTP handler in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, httphandler

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I am using a JavaScript POST method to submit a form to my MVC Controller. It is typically uploading a file to a server. I have multiple pages from which files are uploaded. Files could be images, documents, etc.

I want to add some common, custom functionality before uploading file. Let's say I want to check the file size. This is not possible on the client side, as some clients are using browsers that do not support HTML5.

When I am trying to upload a large file, IIS sends back the request as a 404.13 (content length is large). It does not hit my controller. I tried creating HTTPHandler and RouteHandler, as it is an MVC application. But neither of these work.

Can anybody please suggest how I can create an HTTP handler for this?

Comment: configure IIS to allow larger uploads?

Answer (score 0):

As Jaromanda X said, it looks like you need to configure your IIS to allow working with bigger files. It is a subject that should have been discussed multiple times on this forum so if you search for it you should find an answer.

To not be completely useless :), I will suggest you a source where it is explained how to do that: [Easy ways to upload and validate large files in ASP.NET](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/upload-large-files-asp-net-radasyncupload)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, this is not related to configring IIS to upload large file, i did that already I want an HTTP handler kind of thing to handle requests. Please tell any clue

Comment: @Rohit why do you think its the handler when the error you are getting is about content length? Does the same infrastructure work when you are trying to upload a small file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add/change `httpRuntime` inside configuration of `system.web` like this:

```
<configuration>
...
 <system. web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" /> 
...
 </system .web>
</configuration>
```

where, `maxRequestLength="102400"` is the maximum file size in bytes and the `executionTimeout="3600"` is the maximum execution time you should increase for slower connections. If you have files larger then 30000000 (28.6 MB) files, then tou have to add to `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

See [<httpRuntime> Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx) at MSDN.